# how to see memory layout of struct, class object

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, out-of-memory, cortex-m

I'm on an embedded system and need to wring out an additional couple dozen bytes from the heap.

Once I've built the `.elf`, is there a utility to run so I can output the memory layout of my class objects and structs?

I need to see if there's a way to gain memory by simply changing the layout of members.

Comment: With gcc (at least) you can use the `-Wpadded` option to get a warning every time the compiler inserts padding into your `struct`/`class` - some of that can be avoided, some of it cannot. That's an easy way to find types where shuffling member order has potential to gain a few bytes..

Comment: How is seeing the memory layout of compiled binary off-topic??? What stackexchange site am I supposed to go for this question?

Comment: @JesperJuhl will it give a warning per struct/class?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092415/force-c-structure-to-pack-tightly

Comment: @Adrian Yes. Read the documentation yourself: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: You can probably also get some interesting info from the `objdump`, `readelf` & `nm` tools.

Comment: Many compilers have an option to print out a *map* file, which is a cross reference of all the symbols in your program.  Check your compiler for syntax for generating the *map* file.

Comment: If it is an elf, you may be able to deduce the layout from the ABI specification: [itanium ABI - Chapter 2 Data layout](http://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#layout)

Comment: The rule is basically as much packed as allow the alignment. The vtable pointer is at the top of the struct

Comment: Just for reference, if you're using clang the command line `clang -Xclang -fdump-record-layouts <blah>` dumps this kind of information (and `-Xclang -fno-color-diagnostics` makes it more machine-processable).

Comment: How about viewing the layout on the target?  see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54384590/2785528