# Force a C++ class to have non-aligned members

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2015

Consider this class:

```
class C3
{
public:
    uint16_t p1;
    uint16_t p2;
    uint8_t p3;
};
```

`sizeof(C3)` is `6`. Is there any compiler routine to bypass alignment and force it's size to be `5`? I tried to use `alignas` without success...

Comment: this should be answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092415/force-c-structure-to-pack-tightly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force C++ structure to pack tightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21092415/force-c-structure-to-pack-tightly)

Comment: Your title is misleading. Your structures *are* aligned. Each member is aligned by the compiler and padding needed to ensure that alignment is inserted automatically. From your question it's clear though that what you want is *not* alignment but a *packed* structure without padding.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You are right, and why didn't you simply edit it? I did now. Also, the entities in question are members, not attributes (which do exist in modern C++, but are entirely different things).

Comment: Because this is  platform-dependent you should use a `static_assert(sizeof(C3) == sizeof(C3::p1) + sizeof(C3::p2) + sizeof(C3::p3));` to ensure that the compiler honors whatever compiler option/pragma you use to pack the struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `MSVC` compiler (you have included the VS-2015 tag), you can use the [`#pragma pack`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=vs-2019) directive to set padding options for classes and structures. This also allows you to save/restore 'default' settings, using the `push` and `pop` options.

The following short example demonstrates this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class C3 {
public:
    uint16_t p1;
    uint16_t p2;
    uint8_t p3;
};

#pragma pack(push, 1) // Save current packing and set to single-byte
class C4 {
public:
    uint16_t p1;
    uint16_t p2;
    uint8_t p3;
};
#pragma pack(pop) // Restore saved packing

class C5 {
public:
    uint16_t p1;
    uint16_t p2;
    uint8_t p3;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(C3) << std::endl; // 6
    std::cout << sizeof(C4) << std::endl; // 5
    std::cout << sizeof(C5) << std::endl; // 6 (again)
    return 0;
}
```

Many other compilers support directives *equivalent* to the MSVC `#pragma pack`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to answer by Adrian, you could also do for some compiler that might not support `#pragma pack`:

```
class  C3
{
public:
    uint16_t p1 __attribute__((packed));
    uint16_t p2 __attribute__((packed));
    uint8_t p3;
};
```