# Memory layout of C++ struct with static multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, struct, memory-layout

I have a C++ `struct` containing integers and *static* arrays like so:

```
struct sMyStruct {
    unsigned int uiVal;
    int iVal1;
    int iVal2 = 0;
    float afVals[ NUM_VALUES ];
    unsigned char auiVals[ NUM_VALUES ];
    float aafVals[ NUM_VALUES ][ NUM_VALUES_2 ];
};
```

where `NUM_VALUES` and `NUM_VALUES_2` are `#define`d at compile-time.

Is it safe for me to assume that, allowing for some padding between the members to suit alignment boundaries, each member in this structure, including the arrays, will be laid out consecutively (contiguously) in memory?

I am passing this structure to a LabVIEW application and only the three integers and the first array (`afVals`) are arriving safely.  The last two arrays are getting lost and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Barring padding for alignment purposes the members will be in the order you have defined and the entire object will be in one contiguous piece of memory.

Comment: There are no static arrays. There are only arrays. _"The last two arrays are getting lost and I'm not sure why"_ you should be asking that instead.

Comment: Assuming (since C++11) a standard-layout class (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/classes#Standard-layout_class ), yes.    Bear in mind that the size/alignment of non-`char` types and padding between members is compiler specific (if the labview application assumes different member sizes/alignment and/or different padding than your C++ compiler, all bets are off).

Comment: @PasserBy some arrays are perhaps less static ...  std::cin >> size; int *array = new int[size];

Comment: XY problem. Why are you interested in the layout?

Comment: Yes. As long as you make sure this is a simple structure. If you add public/private/protected things can change.

Comment: If you are sending it somewhere, maybe you would like to [pack it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21092415/21105992)?

Comment: How does labView know the layout of your struct?

Comment: @PasserBy: "static array" is a standard description for an array whose size is determined at compilation time.  Compare "dynamic arrays", whose size is determined at run-time.

Comment: Careful with the word "standard" as it could be inferred that you're referring to the language standard.

Comment: @teapot418 No, just NO. A packed struct sets aligment of all data types to 1 and removes padding. That means access will be unaligned and depending on hardware must be done byte by byte. So accessing an uint64_t in a packed struct will force the compiler to emit 8 byte reads and combine that back into an uint64_t. Never pack a struct with more than one access as performace and code size will be horrible.

Comment: How are you passing the arrays? Show the code. What addresses does end up being used?

Comment: @ÖöTiib "Static", especially in context of structs, means static member. There is no ambiguity with array data members, they can't possibly be dynamically allocated.

Comment: @EdGraham I'm not sure why you think it's a standard description, there is rarely any need to specify how an array is allocated when talking about the array itself so we just say "array". In fact, if we want to be pedantic, there's nothing special about a dynamically allocated array from the C++ standard's perspective, a dynamically allocated array is in all respects the same kind of object as an array on the stack. I'm pretty sure most people will interpret your title as asking whether static members affect layout, which is a very reasonable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to all who posted constructive comments: I think I have my answer now!  It appears that the general consensus is: **yes, I am safe to assume that all members of the structure, including the arrays, will be laid out contiguously in memory** (allowing for any padding inserted for alignment purposes).

Comment: An easy way to be use is add the following to your code: `static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<sMyStruct> == true);`